# There is no 'VBE6EXT. OLB' in the excel provided by the computer

Tags: vba

The Excel provided with the computer does not have 'VBE6EXT. OLB', which makes it impossible to use Visual Basic

I tried to reinstall Excel, but because of the laptop model problem, I could only install it through the files of the computer manufacturer, and their files did not have this function

Comment: What's the laptop model?

Answer (score -1):

I found that file, in the VB6 install directory, even if my excel vba version is 7.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).